# Div 100% height scroll

Tags: css, height

At my page i have a navigation bar to the left that is 100% height and 25% width.
It is working fine, but when there's scroll available, it destroys the background, and make it look ugly. The reason i think is that 100% height is only applied to the active window.
What is the trick to have a div 100% height always, even if the user is scrolling?

Css of the navigation:

```
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    color:#999999;
```

I have tried position:absolute with no results, also tried clear both.
Need help :)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sa6cb/)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Using `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%` should fix it. See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zitrusfrisch/Sa6cb/3/

Comment: This seems to work, but when I do this, I lose the scrolling on the sidenav, which was something I would have liked to keep. Anyone got any ideas on this?

Comment: I guess we'll never know

Comment: Setting `min-height: 100%` and `height: auto` worked for me, when the content exceeded the height of the viewport.

Answer (score 3):

if you want the element to take 100% of the screen use `min-height: 100vh`
and if you want it to take 100% of the parent element use `min-height: 100%`

Comment: Thanks! Been searching for awhile and the `vh` units got me what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use:

```
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I wanted to build an opaque overlay on top of a webpage. The overlay only covered the height of the browser window, not the total scrolling height of the page. I turned to Javascript to dynamically get the page height.

```js
$('body').append('<div style="width:100%;height:'+document.documentElement.scrollHeight+'px;background:#000000;opacity:0.5;position: absolute;top: 0;z-index: 1000;"></div>')
```