# CSS - overlay div height:100% including scroll area is not working

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, overlay

I'm trying to do something very simple.
I have `div` with scroll, and I want the overlay div will cover **all the height**, *including the **scroll area***.
I've tried `min-height:100%` (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757951/div-100-height-scroll)) but it's not working.

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/svfukxjd/2/

```css
.main {
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
  </div>
  <div class="cover">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add in `cover` as a child of the div that has your content.
2. Position `cover` relative to the the content div using:

   ```
   .main > div {
     position: relative;
   }
   ```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
.main {
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.main > div {
  position: relative;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <br>Test
    <div class="cover">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution would not work. Until I realised that I had display: flex; on the main > div box. Removing display: flex made it work like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Change your height from `height:100%;` to `height:100vh;`

```
.cover
{
    position:absolute;
    height:100vh;  
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:green;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IT may be solution to your problem But you have to slightly change your structure.[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/priyasingh/svfukxjd/7/)

```
Add .cover to inside div containing test
```