# Make DIV 100% Scroll Height of Parent

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a div whose scroll height is set by an absolutely positioned child.  I'd like to make add another child (which can be positioned in any way) have 100% the height of the parent's scroll-height.

```css
body {
  background: #334;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.scroller {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, orange, orange 10px, #cc8400 10px, #cc8400 20px);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: auto;
}

.abs {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, purple, purple 10px, #4d004d 10px, #4d004d 20px);
  position: absolute;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.fullHeight {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="abs"></div>
  <div class="fullHeight"></div>
</div>
```

### The Setup

([easier to read version on CodePen](https://codepen.io/SandoCalrissian/pen/wXjzVz))

In this example, the orange-striped box `.scroller` has 2 children:

- `.abs` (purple stripes): an absolutely positioned element that sets the scroll height of `.scroller`
- `.fullHeight` (translucent gray): an element that by whatever means has to be the full scroll-height of `.scroller`

### The Problem

`.fullHeight` takes it's height/width from the display dimensions of `.scroller`.  As soon as you scroll down, `.fullHeight` begins to disappear off the top of the screen.  It should be as tall as `.scroller`'s entire scroll-height.

I've tried using flex-box, putting `.abs` in one column (without absolute positioning) and `.fullHeight` in the other, but `.fullHeight` still maxes out at the display height of `.scroller`.  I've also tried [this black magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757951/div-100-height-scroll), but I'm not even sure how that's *supposed* to work.

### The Question

How can I have a child of a scrollable element of arbitrary scroll-height have a height equal to the scroll-height of its parent?  I'd like to avoid Javascript if at all possible.